# What could cause $user to change while logged in?

Tags: drupal, session

I am seeing a weird bug where occasionally after logging in as user "foo" the username in a logged in block shows "bar" i.e. the $user object has somehow switched from foo to bar.

I've checked all custom modules and the theme to make sure there is no voodoo going on when I use global $user; but no leads.

Also placed additional watchdog messages inside user_authenticate and user_authenticate_finalize but the user object seems to be behaving.

How else can I track this error down?

Comment: Are you sure you're not seeing the block cache in play?

Comment: I've seen block cache issues happen if I am logging in as different users from the same browser while testing. But the user it's logging me in has never used my computer. Is this what you mean?

Answer (score 2):

A user switch can happen with very simple code like this :
global $user;
$some_user = user_load('uid' => SOME_UID);
$user = $some_user;

Perhaps you can try looking at assignments like the last one or uses of global $user

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought. Have done egrep on $user but only have calls to the user objects no assignments.